# WPF theme that looks like Windows XP/WinForms

Tags: wpf, themes

I'm looking for a WPF theme that looks like Windows XP/WinForms. Basically I want all the WPF goodness, but without my business analyst freaking out because the colors look different.

(Pity too, I really like the themes I found on CodePlex.)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't override styles/templates of default controls they will look natively in any Windows theme. Your app will look like XP under XP, like Vista under Vista, and so on.

Just in case: XP theme is called `Luna`. If you need your app to use it under any Windows OS - look for documentation (MSDN) about theming in WPF.

Comment: Not really. There is a vague resemblance, but not anywhere close enough for my purposes.

Comment: if you mean it just "feels" a bit different - then there's probably nothing you can do, WPF renders UI in a completely different way, not using GDI+

Comment: Could you please paste a screenshot showing the difference you want to avoid?